# How could I input multi-line arguments in an embed discord bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make an embed discord bot, and I want to be able to fully edit the message with the command, I have followed some tutorials and I'm able to set the arguments of each parameter, but I can only write one word each.
The idea is to separate with comas and be able to write multiple words and lines.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const token = '';

const PREFIX = '!';

bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Bot online');
});

bot.on('message', message => {

  let args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).split(' ');

  switch (args[0]) {
    case 'embed':
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(args[1])
        .setDescription(args[2])
        .setImage(args[3])
        .setColor(args[4])
        .setFooter(message.author.username)
        .setTimestamp()
      message.channel.send(embed);
      break;
  }
});

bot.login(token);
```

Comment: `let args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).split(' ')` you aren't splitting by commas here